# About memory occupying in .net

Tags: .net

> ```
> Public Function GetTransformation(ByVal xmldata As String, ByVal Xsltpath As String) As String
>     Dim writer As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
>     Dim strXsl As String = String.Empty
>     Try
>         Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform(False)
>         xslt.Load(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, Xsltpath))
>         Dim XmlReader As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(New StringReader(xmldata))
>         xslt.Transform(XmlReader, Nothing, writer)
>         strXsl = writer.ToString()
>         writer.Flush()
>         writer.Dispose()
>         Return strXsl
>     Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
>         Throw
>     End Try
> End Function
> ```

I have the above function to transform an xml to string. 
Can I Use the return statement as like below given

> return  writer.ToString()

instead of the below given expert of the function

> ```
>   strXsl = writer.ToString()
>         writer.Flush()
>         writer.Dispose()
>         Return strXsl
> ```

which is right for minimize use of memory. 
what happened with the variables and streams and etc. which are declared in function after executing function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely use

```
return writer.ToString()
```

- There's no need to flush a `StringWriter`
- There actually no need to dispose it usually... but it's generally a good idea to dispose of all `IDisposable` implementations anyway

The better solution is to use a `Using` statement for the writer, so it *always* gets disposed. Get rid of the pointless `Catch` block, and just change your code to:

```
Public Function GetTransformation(ByVal xmldata As String, ByVal Xsltpath As String) As String
    Using writer As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
        Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform(False)
        xslt.Load(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, Xsltpath))
        Dim XmlReader As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(New StringReader(xmldata))
        xslt.Transform(XmlReader, Nothing, writer)
        Return writer.ToString()
    End Using
End Function
```

You should *very* rarely be calling `Dispose` explicitly - you should almost *always* use a [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) instead.

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet
Thank you very much

Comment: Can you tell me why didnt you use try catch block in your code? is there any special purpose?

Comment: @hiren: What do you believe the `Try` block was accomplishing in the original code? It was just rethrowing whatever exceptions were being thrown - it was pointless.